# Listing all tables a user has query rights on in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query the Oracle database to retrieve a list of tables in all available schemas that the connected user has query rights on. The following query gives me a list of all tables in all schemas but I need to filter these results based on the level of privilege.

```
select OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME from SYS.ALL_TABLES where SECONDARY='N'
```

It's fine if the user has higher privileges than just select on other schemas/tables but select is a minimum requirement. What complicates this further for me is that a user may only have permissions on certain tables of a schema. I'm not sure how I can filter out such tables as well in my result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME
  FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES
 WHERE SECONDARY = 'N' AND OWNER = 'USER1'
UNION ALL
SELECT OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME
  FROM dba_tab_privs
 WHERE GRANTEE = 'USER1' AND privilege = 'SELECT'
```

This give you all tables which user1 is owner and tables which user1 can select. I hope this helps

Comment: It took me some time to look at this but I can say that works but may need some revision. One thing is, I needed to query the all_tab_privs view instead of dba_tab_privs view. dba_tab_privs returned 0 rows. Another problem I'm noticing is that this query returns some tables that a user cannot access, such as those belonging to domain based indexes, something like MDRT_%. I'll need to find a way to exclude those tables. Otherwise, this query is also reasonably fast which is quite an advantage.

Comment: A little further analysis and I realized that MDRT% tables are returned from Oracle 11.2.0.4 onwards. The above query worked perfectly on an Oracle 11.2.0.3 DB. I'll still need to investigate further to find a solution for this problem in newer versions of Oracle.